# Extjs4 - How to move lable and value in special position

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have a panel like **http://jsfiddle.net/7kKVc/**

[image]

I try to move `displayfield` like below

[image]

I try `hideLabel: true,` but that's wrong :(

How to make that thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var filterPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    bodyPadding: 5,  // Don't want content to crunch against the borders
    width: 300,
    title: 'Filters',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'datefield',
        fieldLabel: 'Start date'
    }, {
        hideEmptyLabel: false,
        xtype: 'displayfield',
        value: 'Limit: my value'
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```